# How to Conect MQTT broker to a knative kafka source

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect, knative-eventing

Basically I want to send messages from a MQTT(mosquito) broker to a knative event source(kafka) . In case of a simple kafka broker I could use the confluent's kafkaconnect but in this case it's a knative event source rather than a broker. The problems lies with conversion to cloud events.

Comment: Question doesn't really make sense. Knative Kafka source, by definition, can only read from Kafka, so you'll still need Kafka Connect (and a Kafka cluster) or use an MQTT source, if that exists

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a current MQTT broker which can read/write to Kafka, you might the the [Kafka source](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/sources/kafka-source/) to convert the Kafka messages to CloudEvents and send them to your service.

If you're asking about how to connect the MQTT broker with Kafka, I'd suggest either finding or writing an MQTT source or using something outside the Knative ecosystem.